# Dragon Age Inquisition: The Descent DLC not showing

Tags: pc, technical-issues, dragon-age-inquisition

I've finally gotten around to purchasing The Descent DLC for Dragon Age Inquisition and was pretty exited to play it this weekend. I bought it from the Origin launcher, downloaded/installed it and started up the game, but the mission it was supposed to add to the war table did not show up.

After some initial troubleshooting, I uninstalled the game and re-downloaded the entire thing, but still the DLC content remains elusive. I have confirmed that the content was downloaded to the following location:

```
C:\Games\Dragon Age Inquisition\Update\SinglePlayer_DLCRed
```

This folder is about 2.13 GB in size. Also, though this might be unrelated, my game is unable to connect to the dragon age servers from in-game, stating that:

> You must be signed into Origin to access the online features. Please Go Online in the Origin window and try again.

Off course, there are no sign-in options in the "Origin" window, since I am signed in. I am not interested in the multiplayer/keep features, so this does not bother me overly much.

Somewhere I read that you could try deleting the cache in Appdata:

```
\AppData\Roaming\Origin
```

This did not resolve anything, though. I did purchase the previous DLC, Jaws of Hakkon, and played it without any issues whatsoever. I also read somewhere that some people have issues loading the DLC while mods are enabled. I do not know what they are referring to as "mods", but I'm sure that I do not have anything like that installed.

Comment: I've tried contacting EA on the Live Chat they have on help.ea.com, but after a lot of waiting, I never get connected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to for the DLC to show up, it needs to be verified by logging in from within the game. Logging in to just Origin is apparently not enough.

If you find that you are unable to log in from within the game, and your Origin account is already logged in, you may need to re-install Origin.

Comment: Yes, re-installing origin is what does the trick

Comment: Glad it helped!